# Error:- The ITransactionLocal interface is not supported by the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider.Are there any pre requisites?

Tags: c#, c, ms-office, connection-string

Through different API I arrive to the same code with the same parameters

```
public void Foo(string nprPath, int maxConnections = 3)
{
    var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + nprPath;

    using (var connectionPool = new ConnectionPool(maxConnections, connectionString))
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

I enter the mefhod with the exact param. 
One API succeeds and the other throws the following

```
{"The ITransactionLocal interface is not supported by the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' 
provider.Local transactions are unavailable with the current provider."}
```

Are there any prerequisites  to using ACE.OLEDB.12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try to add `";OLE DB Services=-4"` to connection string.

Something like this:

```
var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;OLE DB Services=-4;Data Source=" + nprPath;
```

Also check this related **[forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/470ac632-3c9e-47c1-9b72-65777ddab009/the-itransactionlocal-interface-is-not-supported?forum=wcf)**.

**EDIT:-**

When "OLE DB Services = -4; the it means:-

> All except pooling and automatic transaction enlistment

Check the related **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: Excellent. Solved. Saved me hours, I assume. Do you have an Idea why was it different?

Comment: @rails:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps! :)